# In Drupal 7 jquery library is not getting called in module

Tags: jquery, drupal-7

I have tried all the ways to include libraries in my module none of them worked.

**How can I call a library in my module?**

In `sites/all/libraries/jquery` the library `jquery-1.11.3.js` is present.
But when I load the page, it does not find the library.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is already available with Drupal. You don't have to download it as a library package.

If you're trying to use a different version of jQuery, I recommend using the contributed module [jQuery Update](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update) instead.

Otherwise, it's more likely that you'll have issues with jQuery and especially with the admin theme and overall usability.

Comment: Thanks Osman.. I am using jQuery update module. I have to use 2 different jQuery versions. I used no conflict script as well. For datatables I have to call jquery-1.11.3.js. This file I kept it in libraries folder. Can you help me with this?

Comment: @Dhanashree you need to provide more details. Please explain, what you've tried so far, what works what doesn't, error messages, etc. Please consult to [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before editing your question.